# Какие технологии используются на этом сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, svg

Интересуют, в частности, [этот](http://brightmedia.pl/?lang=en&site=intro) сайт  . 
Расскажите (или дайте ссылки) на технологии, которые тут используются. Как они связаны между собой? С чего начать и куда двигаться? Или какие то специальные техники и приёмы создания подобных сайтов?

Comment: это не сайт для фриланса, где могут сделать всю работу за вас, поэтому рекомендую самому освоить браузерные инструменты разработчика и научиться смотреть что и как сделано на любом сайте, вот для начала: https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо делать такие сайты, они отвратительны

Answer (score 0):

Стандартные html, css, javascript - отслеживается сколько событие прокрутки окна(скроллинг) и выполняется анимация. Библиотек как для анимаций так и для spy-scrolling пруд пруди.

Касательно реализации есть разные фишки. В данном пример есть два типа анимаций - линии, которые растягиваются вместе со скроллингом и фигуры, которые в какой-то момент отрисовываются.

**Фигуры**

Например, в самом верху ромбик с 00 не может быть нарисован наполовину(можешь стрелочкам помотать вверх вниз), при определённом расстонии он ли появляется либо исчезает. Псевдокод такой:

```
//переменная скрол хранит значение скролла:) Если оно становится 500, происходит 
//запуск анимаций, которые уничтожают верхний ромбик с 00
var figure00 = false; //если фигура отрисована, то не надо её повторно рисовать
if(scroll == 500) {
     if(figure00 == true) {
         destroyFigure00();
         figure00 = false;
     }
}else if(scroll == 499) {
     if(figure00 == false) {
         createFigure00();
         figure00 = true;
     }
}
```

**Линии**

Создаётся блок - div, у него делается видимой одна граница, используется rotation. В js при прокрутке просто меняем высоту блока. Таких блоков может быть сколько угодно.

```
html
<div class="firstLine"></div>

css
.firstLine {
    border-left: 1px black solid;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

javascript
function onScroll() {
    //линия начнёт рисовать при достижении scroll значения 700
    var height = scroll - 700; 
    if(height >= 0 && height < maxHeight) {
        $('.firstLine').css('heigt', height);
    }
}
```

**Заключение**

Анимации фигур я бы сделал также, как и линии - нарисовал блоки в html, css, потом просто задал анимации для их отображения.

Чтобы разобраться во всём досконольно, придётся либо кому-то платить, чтобы он тебе код набрал и всё рассказал, либо копаться в js+css+html. Во втором случае следует начать с простого, например, сделать слайдер с анимацией, потом что-нибудь посложнее, скорее всего для любой идеи, если у самого не получается, можно будет найти пример кода в интернете и разбираться с ним.

Самый простой вариант для javascript - изучить **JQuery** и плагины под него, например, **spy-scrolling jquery**